# Fatal Error allowed memory size is exhausted with WordPress plugin WP-Typography

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, apache2

I recently installed the plugin WP-Typography in a WordPress website.

Now, every second time I open a site from this webiste, I get this PHP error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in …/wp-typography/vendor/mundschenk-at/wp-data-storage/src/class-transients.php on line 128

Here the function of the PHP file. The line 128 is the return statement at the bottom.

```
/**
 * Retrieves a cached large object.
 *
 * @param string $key The cache key.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function get_large_object( $key ) {
    $encoded = $this->get( $key );
    if ( false === $encoded ) {
        return false;
    }

    $uncompressed = @\gzdecode( \base64_decode( $encoded ) ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
    if ( false === $uncompressed ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->maybe_fix_object( \unserialize( $uncompressed ) ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
}
```

I basically understand server issues, I also understand programming and PHP but I was hoping that anyone knows this problem before I start tracking down the whole plugin.

The PHP memory limit of the webserver is 64M. It does not change anything if I increase it. I also added the two following lines to the php.ini and it also did not change the behaviour.

> realpath_cache_size = 16k
>
> realpath_cache_ttl = 120

Here some others information:

> PHP Version: 5.6.33-0+deb8u1
>
> Apache Version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

Comment: Speak to your host, they're probably capping your memory.

Comment: some plugins can override memory limit

Comment: I consider 128M to be absolute minimum for WP to run OK with some plugins installed, but I'd still recommend 256M for each WP instance (again, depending on number and type of plugins installed).

Answer (score 0):

The issue really isn't those lines in the one plugin; it sounds like the host has capped php memory usage for each account in their global php configs. Ask them.

You can *try* these settings in `wp-config.php`, but there's no guarantee they will override the hosts' settings:

```
// memory for each php process
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');

// memory for WP admin
define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional information: I am my own host. I can set any PHP setting but I read in other forums, that it isn't just the memory limit with this error. 
I just tried it with 256MB but it still throws this error. 
Please tell me which PHP settings I have to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your PHP memory limit (maybe in addition to the WordPress define). The error is triggered by wp-Typography, but not caused by it. Be sure to double check in which `php.ini` you have increased `memory_limit`. You probably have different ones for CLI, CGI and PHP-FPM.